# I got these error after trying to insert a row in a table and have created a trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql

i'm getting these error:

```
INSERT INTO "DANIEL"."STATION" (NUM_STATION, NOM_STATION, ALTITUDE, REGION) 
VALUES ('6', 'Baalbak', '1250', 'Baalbek')
ORA-04091: table DANIEL.STATION is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "DANIEL.TRUPDATE_HIST_STATION", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'DANIEL.TRUPDATE_HIST_STATION'
ORA-06512: at line 1


One error saving changes to table "DANIEL"."STATION":
Row 6: ORA-04091: table DANIEL.STATION is mutating, trigger/function may not 
see it
ORA-06512: at "DANIEL.TRUPDATE_HIST_STATION", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'DANIEL.TRUPDATE_HIST_STATION'
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

after inserting a row in table station

And here is the code of the trigger that i just wrote:

```
create or replace TRIGGER trupdate_hist_station
  AFTER INSERT ON STATION
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  V_num_station NUMBER;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    SELECT s.NUM_STATION
      INTO v_num_station
      FROM STATION s
      WHERE s.NUM_STATION = :NEW.NUM_STATION;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
      v_num_station :=0;
  END;

 INSERT INTO HIST_STATION
    ("NUM_STATION","ANNEE","NB_RESERV","REVENU")
  VALUES
    (V_num_station,(SELECT to_char(SYSDATE,'YYYY')FROM DUAL),0,0);
END trupdate_hist_station;
```

i just need to add a new row in Hist_table after adding a row in table Station

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to `SELECT` anything from the table you're inserting into (that's what causes *mutation*).

Also, get rid of double quotes, they aren't necessary as column names are defaulted to uppercase anyway.

Furthermore, don't `SELECT` year from `dual` - **extract** it from `SYSDATE`.

This should do:

```
create or replace TRIGGER trupdate_hist_station
  AFTER INSERT ON STATION
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO HIST_STATION  
    (num_station, annee, nb_reserv, revenu)
 VALUES
    (:new.num_station, extract (year from sysdate), 0, 0);
END trupdate_hist_station;
```